# How to stop notifications when people 'like' my post

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

When I post a status in Facebook, I get notified whenever someone likes my post. How can I stop that?

Answer (score 2):

To stop getting notified whenever someone likes your post, click "v" on top right of the post, then click "Turn off notification"

Comment: Thanks! But I meant to do this automatically for all posts.